# 64 bit programming and compilation- visual studio 2008 or visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit

For 64 bit programming and compilation - Which is better and advantageous visual studio 2008 or visual studio 2010?

Comment: I used both VS2005 and VS2010 for 64-bit developments (I skipped VS2008) and see no big differences regarding 64-bit developments.  I would suggest using VS2010, not specifically for 64-bit, but for all the new C++0x functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use VS2010 SP1. They added new optimizations, support for new CPU extensions to the C++ compiler there, and 64-bit Intellitrace.

Release notes for SP1 are here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509

Answer (score 3):

In my experience there were several serious bugs that manifested in the 64-bit version of the Visual Studio 2008 debugger.  It would get confused between objects and pointers to objects (requiring an extra * when you tried to put the object in the Watch Window).  Calling user-defined functions on complex objects from the Immediate Window would mysteriously fail or hang.  I reported these bugs to the Microsoft VC++ compiler team, and they fixed them in Visual Studio 2010, where I have had no 64-bit debugger problems.  Therefore I can offer you some solid evidence to prefer VS2010 to VS2008.